# JHipster: I can't add thiered party dependency like 'angular-2-dropdown-multiselect'

Tags: spring-boot, angular5, jhipster

I have added angular2-dropdown-multiselect in Jhipster angular part. Its not working perfectly as per the angular2-dropdwon-multi select or ngx-treeview I have added the dependency using

```
 npm install angular2-multiselect-dropdown --save
```

Then I have added the same into app.module.ts

```
import { AngularMultiSelectModule } from 'angular2-multiselect-dropdown/angular2-multiselect-dropdown';

@NgModule({
  // ...
  imports: [
    AngularMultiSelectModule,
  ]
  // ...
})
```

Then Try this following example

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    dropdownList = [];
    selectedItems = [];
    dropdownSettings = {};
    ngOnInit(){
        this.dropdownList = [
                              {"id":1,"itemName":"India"},
                              {"id":2,"itemName":"Singapore"},
                              {"id":3,"itemName":"Australia"},
                              {"id":4,"itemName":"Canada"},
                              {"id":5,"itemName":"South Korea"},
                              {"id":6,"itemName":"Germany"},
                              {"id":7,"itemName":"France"},
                              {"id":8,"itemName":"Russia"},
                              {"id":9,"itemName":"Italy"},
                              {"id":10,"itemName":"Sweden"}
                            ];
        this.selectedItems = [
                                {"id":2,"itemName":"Singapore"},
                                {"id":3,"itemName":"Australia"},
                                {"id":4,"itemName":"Canada"},
                                {"id":5,"itemName":"South Korea"}
                            ];
        this.dropdownSettings = { 
                                  singleSelection: false, 
                                  text:"Select Countries",
                                  selectAllText:'Select All',
                                  unSelectAllText:'UnSelect All',
                                  enableSearchFilter: true,
                                  classes:"myclass custom-class"
                                };            
    }
    onItemSelect(item:any){
        console.log(item);
        console.log(this.selectedItems);
    }
    OnItemDeSelect(item:any){
        console.log(item);
        console.log(this.selectedItems);
    }
    onSelectAll(items: any){
        console.log(items);
    }
    onDeSelectAll(items: any){
        console.log(items);
    }
}
```

with HTML

```
<angular2-multiselect [data]="dropdownList" [(ngModel)]="selectedItems" 
    [settings]="dropdownSettings" 
    (onSelect)="onItemSelect($event)" 
    (onDeSelect)="OnItemDeSelect($event)"
    (onSelectAll)="onSelectAll($event)"
    (onDeSelectAll)="onDeSelectAll($event)">
</angular2-multiselect>
```

But after runing `yarn serve`

it just showing

[image]

Please help me

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem with another third party library (ngx-treeview) and I also was only getting the html component empty and with no errors in the javascript console.

It was solved after importing the third party library properly following the JHipster project structure. If you want to use an external module in more than one module component, which is common, you need to configure it in **shared-libs.module.ts** and also add it to **imports** and to the **exports** on its @NgModule configuration.

src\main\webapp\app\shared\shared-libs.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { NgJhipsterModule } from 'ng-jhipster';
import { InfiniteScrollModule } from 'ngx-infinite-scroll';
import { CookieModule } from 'ngx-cookie';
import { FontAwesomeModule } from '@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome';
import { TreeviewModule } from 'ngx-treeview';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        NgbModule.forRoot(),
        NgJhipsterModule.forRoot({
            alertAsToast: false,
            i18nEnabled: true,
            defaultI18nLang: 'en'
        }),
        InfiniteScrollModule,
        CookieModule.forRoot(),
        FontAwesomeModule,
        TreeviewModule.forRoot()  // new third party lib import
    ],
    exports: [FormsModule, CommonModule, NgbModule, NgJhipsterModule, 
              InfiniteScrollModule, FontAwesomeModule, 
              TreeviewModule] // new third party lib export
})
export class MyProjectSharedLibsModule {}
```

Share-libs module is generated by Jhipster and it is by default imported in shared.module which is imported by app.module and also the other modules that are created at start by Jhipster. For more about project structure: https://www.jhipster.tech/using-angular/

However, if you create a new angular module component you need to add the shared module in the imports to be able to use the third parties libraries there.

```
@NgModule({
   ...
    imports: [MyProjectSharedModule,
              RouterModule.forChild([HOME_ROUTE])],
   ..
})
export class MyProjectAnotherModule {}
```